# When this attribute is displayed on the product page, its values must be different depending on the selected language

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, eav-attributes

You need to add a new text attribute to all products in the Magento store. When this attribute is displayed on the product page, its values must be different
depending on the selected language.
Keeping simplicity in mind, how do you add this attribute?

A. Use the Magento CLI to create a new custom attribute, then generate dictionaries for all supported languages

B. Use a Data Patch to create a new EAV attribute

C. Add a new column to the catalog_product_entity table using declarative schema

D. Use the admin panel to create a new extension attribute

can anyone please answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is already a feature of Magento. As well as you had create an store view and also the attribute that supports it. You will be able to change the value of the attribute per store view independently

I would use a data patch to create the attribute.

If you are creating an attribute option, you will also be able to define the label separated by store view.

Good Luck.